# Bootstrap Progress Bar not Showing in the Browser with VueJs

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4, progress-bar, vue-component

I am using **Vue2** (webpack-simple) and i want to add a **bootstrap** progress-bar in a component, it's showing in the component, but **without** the visual progression (aria-valuenow).

I put all the **scripts** possible :
--> bootstrap css, jquery, popper and boostrap js.

Do I **miss** something?

Here is my index.html file -->

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Vue Components</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arizonia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here my Counter.vue component file -->

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h4>Quotes Added</h4>
        <div class="progress" style="height: 20px;">
            <div 
                class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info"
                role="progressbar"
                style="width: 50%"
                aria-valuenow="50"
                aria-valuemin="0"
                aria-valuemax="100"
                >
                50%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    h4 {
        text-align: left;
    }
</style>
```

I was expecting to be render in my browser a progress-bar with 50% of progress already. But it's just 0%. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Change this code :-

```
<div 
            class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info"
            role="progressbar"
            style="width: 50%"
            aria-valuenow="50"
            aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100"
            >
            50%
        </div>
```

As

```
<div 
            class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-info"
            role="progressbar"
            style="width: 50%"
            aria-valuenow="50"
            aria-valuemin="50"
            aria-valuemax="100"
            >
            50%
        </div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! This reads kind of counter-intuitive. Could you still add an explanation why this works?